# Visual Studio Code appears to kill my GCP VMs during Remote SSH

Tags: apache, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I managed to connect to my GCP (Ubuntu) instance from VS Code via remote-ssh but something it's doing appears to kill my VM instances. I can hit the server with the external IP and apache continues to run, but the virtual hosts are inaccessible.

Don't see anything meaningful in the logs. (It's possible that I'm not looking at the right one.)

Restarting the instance and Apache a few times appears to fix it, inexplicably.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We probably want to look in Cloud Logging to see what (if anything) is logged by the Compute Engine.  In addition, the Compute Engine has a "serial console" that one can examine from Cloud Console to see if something else is being reported.  If you don't use VS Code, can you SSH in from Cloud Console?

Comment: To suggest any solutions we need more details like logs. Now we can only guess.

Comment: happens very frequently as well, especially when doing something with docker volume mounts